# Please suggest web site checker, To find PDF documents on the while site

Tags: open-source, software-development, pdf, php, web

Please suggest web site checker, To find PDF documents on the whole site

Answer (score 1):

You can find pdfs on a site via google by typing something like this in google 
e.g. to search for pdf's that contain "abc"

> "abc" site:my_sample_site_address.com filetype:pdf

where "my_sample_site_address.com" is the address of the site you want to search.

If you simply want all pdfs, omit the "abc" bit i.e.

> site:my_sample_site_address.com filetype:pdf

Answer (score 0):

What kind of access do you have? Is it your site, or someone elses?

When I've had to do similar for work, I simply used `wget` to mirror the site, including directory info, and only retain PDF files (well, I had to do word docs, but same same).